# Как в Button задать текст с EditText

Tags: java, android-studio, button, android-edittext, android-alertdialog

Вот я нажал на кнопку Добавить, появилось диалоговое окно с вводом текста, я ввожу текст и нажимаю далее, окно закрывается, и LinerLayout появляется кнопка, я хотел что бы в кнопке которую я создал был текст который я написал в EditText. В ней должны присутствовать буквы, символы и цифры. И дополнительно спрошу как задать id с текстом "Group1, 2, 3 и так далее " в зависимости сколько раз я создам группу?

Пожалуйста помогите, курсовую надо сделать. Тот первый ответ я не понял, извини меня.

Вот мой код

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
    final int groupIdNum = 4004;
    int groupIs = 11;

    LinearLayout MainScrollVertical =
        (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.MainScrollVertical);

    Button CreateGroup = new Button(getApplicationContext());

    CreateGroup.setText(groupIs++);
    CreateGroup.setLayoutParams(
        new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
    );
    CreateGroup.setId(groupIdNum + 1);
    MainScrollVertical.addView(CreateGroup);
}
```

Comment: тут я не понятно вопрос задал, и поэтому обратно задал вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Из описания вопроса не совсем понятно, что Вам нужно сделать. Если Вам нужно по нажатию на кнопку инкрементировать число, введённое в EditText, можете попробовать сделать это следующим образом:

```
mButton = findViewById(R.id.your_button);
mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        EditText mEditText = findViewById(R.id.your_edittext);
        try {
            int numberInEditText =
                Integer.parseInt(mEditText.getText().toString());
            mEditText.setText(String.valueOf(++numberInEditText));
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            ...
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: перед выводом на экран число (тип int) нужно преобразовать в строку (тип String)

Comment: @pavlofff, да, изменила ответ

Comment: Извините либо это не то что мне нужно, либо я просто не понимаю.